# error while installing samba 4.6.5 on ubuntu 16.04 samba/bin/asn1_compile: not found

Tags: networking, samba, active-directory, domain-server, samba4

error while installing samba 4.6.5 on Ubuntu 16.04

> samba/bin/asn1_compile: not found

I'm trying to install samba 4 and after clone using this command:

```
git clone -b v4-6-stable git://git.samba.org/samba.git
```

then started the installation process I got the above error.

Do anyone know how to pass this?
I also checked:

https://lists.samba.org/archive/samba-technical/2012-December/089380.html

Answer (score 0):

I googled for the error then tried this solution and it worked with me:

```
root@dc01:/home/ubuntu/4/samba# make
```

and the compiling started and finished successfully.

then tried the install command install only but this is not working, so tried again:

```
root@dc01:/home/ubuntu/4/samba# make install
```

and it worked after the isolated compiling process
and this is the resault:

```
'install' finished successfully (2m37.689s)
```

And below "How to Create a Network Share Via Samba Via CLI" may you need it.

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/How%20to%20Create%20a%20Network%20Share%20Via%20Samba%20Via%20CLI%20%28Command-line%20interface/Linux%20Terminal%29%20-%20Uncomplicated%2C%20Simple%20and%20Brief%20Way%21